# Update JSON format from other JSON file

Tags: python, json, merge

I have two files which are a and b. I want to import certain information from data b to data a with the unique id from every response.

data

```
a= [{'id':'abc23','name':'aa','age':'22',
     'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
     'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}},
     {'id':'abc25','name':'bb','age':'32',
      'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
      'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}},
    {'id':'abc60','name':'cc','age':'24',
     'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
     'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}}]

b=[{'id':'abc23','read':'2','speak':'abc','write':'2'},
   {'id':'abc25','read':'3','speak':'def','write':'3'},
   {'id':'abc60','read':'5','speak':'dgf','write':'1'}]
```

Code that I used to import from b to a :

```
from pprint import pprint

for dest in a:
    for source in b:
        if source['id'] == dest['id']:
            dest['data'].update(source)
pprint(a)
```

Output from the code that i used :

```
[{  'age': '22',
    'data': {'id': 'abc23', 'read': '2', 'speak': 'abc', 'write': '2'},
    'id': 'abc23',
    'name': 'aa',
    'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {  'age': '32',
    'data': {'id': 'abc25', 'read': '3', 'speak': 'def', 'write': '3'},
    'id': 'abc25',
    'name': 'bb',
    'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {  'age': '24',
    'data': {'id': 'abc60', 'read': '5', 'speak': 'dgf', 'write': '1'},
    'id': 'abc60',
    'name': 'cc',
    'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}]
```

But... This is the output that I want:

```
[{'age': '22',
  'data': {'read': '2', 'speak': 'abc'},
  'id': 'abc23',
  'name': 'aa',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {'age': '32',
  'data': {'read': '3', 'speak': 'def'},
  'id': 'abc25',
  'name': 'bb',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {'age': '24',
  'data': {'read': '5', 'speak': 'dgf'},
  'id': 'abc60',
  'name': 'cc',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't work the way you want with your code.

You do

`dest['data'].update(source)`

where source is
`{'id':'abc23','read':'2','speak':'abc','write':'2'}`

and `dest['data']` is `{'read':'','speak':''}`.

When you `update` it will add all key-value pairs to `dest['data']` and preserve the ones that won't be overwritten.

```
from pprint import pprint

for dest in a:
    for source in b:
        if source['id'] == dest['id']:
            dest['data'] = {k: v for k, v in source.items() if k in dest.get('data', {})}

pprint(a)
```

This one will look for all the fields that are 'updateable' for each case. You might want to hardcode it, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach by changing `b` to a `dict` for easy lookup.

**Ex:**

```
a= [{'id':'abc23','name':'aa','age':'22',
     'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
     'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}},
     {'id':'abc25','name':'bb','age':'32',
      'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
      'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}},
    {'id':'abc60','name':'cc','age':'24',
     'data':{'read':'','speak':''},
     'responses':{'a':1,'b':2}}]

b=[{'id':'abc23','read':'2','speak':'abc','write':'2'},
   {'id':'abc25','read':'3','speak':'def','write':'3'},
   {'id':'abc60','read':'5','speak':'dgf','write':'1'}]

b = {i.pop('id'): i for i in b}   #Convert to dict key = ID & value = `read`, `speak`, `write`

for i in a:
    i['data'].update(b[i['id']])   #Update list
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'age': '22',
  'data': {'read': '2', 'speak': 'abc', 'write': '2'},
  'id': 'abc23',
  'name': 'aa',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {'age': '32',
  'data': {'read': '3', 'speak': 'def', 'write': '3'},
  'id': 'abc25',
  'name': 'bb',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
 {'age': '24',
  'data': {'read': '5', 'speak': 'dgf', 'write': '1'},
  'id': 'abc60',
  'name': 'cc',
  'responses': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}]
```

Comment: Thanks but the first output that i want don't have 'write'. Do you have any idea?